Private C++20 modules
In c++20 there is "modules" feature; I'm interested in having a private module, which can be used only inside my library and is not available for the users of my library, is that possible?
I expect to have something like this:
//my_lib/private_module.ixx
export module my_lib_private_module;
...

//my_lib/public_module.ixx
export module my_lib_public_module;
import my_lib_private_module;

//some user code
import my_lib_public_module; //OK
import my_lib_private_module; //this must fail!

I experimented a bit, but without any success. I'm using CMake to configure my library, should I have any modules specific stuff there?

I'm not good with modules, but I don't think you can prevent some from importing a module while allowing others. You can however create private module fragments within a module - or partition a module. Neither will be available from the outside. I think in your case, your public module could just have a private fragment.

@TedLyngmo but that is what i want to achieve(it it is possible, of course) - just like i have some private classes and functions which i use inside my library and i exclude them from my public interface, in the same way i'd like to have some library-only modules which cannot be accessed from outside the library

@You can have private module fragments in your modules that won't be included in the public interface. Just like if you create a library. What you are asking about sounds however more like you'd like to include one library in another library but not expose the first library's functions etc.

@TedLyngmo yes, that is exactly what i want - to be able to have a module inside 1 library and have it unavailable for another

To achieve the desired behavior of having a private module in C++20 that is only accessible within your library and not to the users of your library, you can use the module keyword without the export keyword for the private module. This way, the private module will not be exported and thus not available for import by users of your library.
Here's a step-by-step guide:
Define the private module without exporting it:
// my_lib/private_module.ixx
module my_lib_private_module;
// Private module implementation

Define the public module and import the private module:
// my_lib/public_module.ixx
export module my_lib_public_module;
import my_lib_private_module;
// Public module implementation

When a user tries to import the private module, it should fail because it is not exported.
// some_user_code.cpp
import my_lib_public_module; // OK
import my_lib_private_module; // This should fail

By following these steps,
the private module my_lib_private_module will only be accessible within your library and not to the users of your library.  The key is to avoid using the export keyword for the private module.

i tried this approach, and when i import my private module - i have an error that it is not found
